# Isomorphism between homology groups of closed homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was trying to prove a result and I ended up with the following problem. Any solution without alexander's duality would help

> If $A$ and $B$ are closed homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then show that
> $H_n(\mathbb{R}^n-A) \cong H_n(\mathbb{R}^n-B)$

I find it hard dealing with complements of $A$ and $B$. There is no known map between $A$ and $B$ and hence I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Here's a hint: the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic is actually irrelevant.

Comment: @EricWofsey still couldn't figure out/

Comment: @zero2infinity The two complements are open subsets of a manifold, so...